# Browser is stuck while another tab is loading

Tags: javascript, ajax

On my website, there is a page that is doing ajax call that can take a few minutes. 
While the ajax is working, if we open a new tab and try to load other pages in the website, they won't load until the ajax is completed. 
The internet is working, and we can load other websites while the ajax is working.

So it seems that there is something in the browser that is not allowing loading a new page from the same website, while there is an ajax call still in progress for the same website.

This is the outline of my ajax call that is blocking other loading of pages from my site:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    timeout:150000,  //TIMEOUT AFTER 150 SECS
        data: {
            mydata: mydata
        },

    complete : function(result) { 
        console.log("ajax complete");   
    },

    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      console.log("error :AJAX completed w/error." +xhr.status+" "+thrownError);    

    },

    success:function(obj  ){
        console.log("ajax success");    
    }
});
```

Any ideas if there is something to fix this issue?

**UPDATE**

the returned data is pretty small. the server usage is low when this happens, since most of the wait is related to an api call to a 3rd party server.

also, this happens only if the pages are loaded from the same browser. If ajax is called from one browser and another page is loaded from a different browser, there is no delay.

Comment: Is the data being returned a huge JSON object?

Comment: It could also be serverside, as in the server fails to respond till it has completed processing the first request. Ajax on a separate tab, cannot affect new page loading client side.

Comment: the returned data is pretty small. the server is usage is low when this happens, since most of the wait is related to an api call to a 3rd party server.